# Lookup value is available in array but VLOOKUP or MATCH functions give error

Tags: excel

Ref. Attached screen shot of excel sheet with problem..

Cell C4 is derived by simple formula, and I am trying to lookup at D6 with same value in A4 (manually entered value). Both cells A4 & C4 are in number format, both have same value 0.6, and when I am checking with `=A4=C4` then it is giving result as `TRUE`. But when I do `VLOOKUP` or `MATCH`, it is giving error `#N/A`.

I want to know what is the difference between cell A4 & C4 so that `VLOOKUP` or `MATCH` functions are not working? And what is the way to eliminate this error?

[Screen shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDR3d.jpg)

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish. Your formula (`= VLOOKUP(D4,B4,1,FALSE)`) is trying to lookup the value of cell `D4` in the range `B4`. So it is looking for the value `TRUE` (the value in cell `D4`) in a cell range that is blank (cell `B4`) which is why you are getting an error. What are you trying to lookup?

Comment: Sorry , I uploaded incorrect picture.

Comment: And correct picture uploaded now.

Comment: Lookup is working if I do paste special value & do text to column in cell C4 , but the problem is I want to keep all formula live.

Comment: Why do you not put in D6 the formula =A4 ? You are only searching a one cell range. What do you mean by keep formula live? Are you moving the formula? Then put = $A$4. The formula will update whenever the value in A4 changes.

Comment: I attached a picture is just to describe the problem in simple way, my actual data set is quite huge & I am facing this problem there.

Comment: Seems that it is Excel bug. The problem appears only when I add 0.2 in cell C3 & C4.   If I add number other than 0.2 in cell C3 & C4 and change matching value in cell A4 (manually entered value ) than V Lookup is working !!  Experts to check & confirm.